Build failing from child module with Maven multi-module setup with dynamic revision
I am trying to utilize maven multi-module setup with dynamic revision, so that version of all the children modules can be managed centrally.
I have uploaded the project here:
When I execute maven install from the root, the build is successful.
Here is the dependency tree from the child2_child:
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ child2_child ---
[INFO] myTest:child2_child:jar:1.0-test
[INFO] \- myTest:child1_child:jar:1.0-test:compile

When I build from child2 or from child2/child2_child, I am getting the following:
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/myTest/child1/$%7Brevision%7D/child1-$%7Brevision%7D.pom
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
....
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project child2_child: Could not resolve dependencies for project myTest:child2_child:jar:1.0-test: Failed to collect dependencies at myTest:child1_child:jar:1.0-test: Failed to read artifact descriptor for myTest:child1_child:jar:1.0-test: 
Could not find artifact myTest:child1:pom:${revision} in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

even though the effective pom has the following:
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>myTest</groupId><artifactId>child1_child</artifactId><version>1.0-test</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>

Environment:
mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.9.9 (8e8579a9e76f7d015ee5ec7bfcdc97d260186937)
Maven home: C:\unzipped\apache-maven-3.9.9
Java version: 17.0.8, vendor: Red Hat, Inc., runtime: D:\unzipped\java-17-openjdk-17.0.8.0.7-1.win.x86_64
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"


I bet you don't have configured the flatten-maven-plugin as decribed in the documentation? BTW: Upgrade all your plugin versions to most recent ones (check here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/)

After I've taken a look into your example project... I say add the configuration for the flatten-maven-plugin as I mentioned ... it's stated in the documentation!! https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html#install-deploy

@khmarbaise, Thanks a lot for your immediate response, it worked
